# HTML5 Javascript Mobile App not fitting on smaller resolution tablets

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile

I am using the Kendo UI Mobile framework and I have min-width attribute set to 768px. When I pull the page up on a tablet with a smaller resolution, it causes a horizontal scroll. I just want the page to auto zoom out if the resolution is smaller than the set width. In the past I have used this meta tag to fix this:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />`

But this is not working.

Any help on how I can have the page auto zoom to fit the devices width would be great

Comment: Try this meta tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 1):

You could also try getting rid of the "minimum width" CSS attribute and just using "width:100%" which would make it fit to any browser size.  There is also some speculation about using ems instead of px for width since there are so many different mobile devices and browsers it's basically impossible to plan for every contingency.  Unfortunately I can't find the link to the article about using em, but basically if you take away some of those hard lower boundaries you might find it's easier to support a bigger variety of devices.

Also checkout [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).  It's a pretty good responsive design package.

Comment: The problem is that my content(table data) gets really messed up if its smaller than 768px. If I remove the min-width it does scale to fit the screen, but at the cost of distorting my view.

Comment: How do you handle it for phones?  Those devices would generally be smaller than a tablet, too.  I think you're looking at a situation where you really can't please everybody all the time.  My advice:  either reduce the font size of the information in the table for screens smaller than 768px or hide less-needed columns at those smaller widths.  If you look around at the web, sites regularly hide information on mobile versions, or condense it in some way.  Otherwise maybe you'll just have to live with people scrolling or pinching your page.

Comment: Another thought, change the content in your table to hide part of the text unless someone taps "more..." or something whenever the screen size is that small.  That solution would probably require some javascript but it could be a reasonable compromise between hiding an entire column and the other options.

Comment: its starting to look like thats what im going to need to do. But, zooming out like the browser already lets me do makes it work. Im just trying to make it happen automatically for the user.

Comment: I agree with @Matt. You can try also media queries in your css to make screen specific styles to fit mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,    minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
```

Comment: Gave this a try.. No dice.. Not sure if it matters, but the device that is not rendering correctly is a Android nexus 7